# How to fix React-Native Error 'could not unzip gradle-5.4.1-all.zip'

Tags: react-native

I have created a project HelloWorld in react native by using react-native init HelloWorld

When I run the project by using react-native run-android command, i am facing error 
could not unzip gradle-5.4.1-all.zip

I have tried the following
1.updated react native
2.wipe the data from Emulator.

Comment: uplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43950483/gradle-build-failed-unable-to-unzip

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle build failed - unable to unzip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43950483/gradle-build-failed-unable-to-unzip)

Answer (score 17):

To resolve this kind of error the following steps are used

1. Open My computer.
2. Navigate the following folder
   C:\Users\UserName.gradle\wrapper\dists
3. Delete the 'gradle-5.4.1-all.zip' folder
4. Run React-native project by using react-native run-android command.
5. The system will download updated gradle-5.4.1-all.zip file so
   internet connection must be ON

Comment: I deleted the gradle files from here: C:\Users\<username>\.gradle\wrapper\dists and that worked